# New Teams Client does not honor Permission Policy for Teams Apps with Chat component? (You cannot send messages to this bot)

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

A custom Teams App that has worked for 5+ years on classic Teams across all Teams clients (web, desktop, mobile).  App has a chat component (chatbot) and static tabs.

App is deployed in organization Teams Portal by Teams Admin.  It is part of Global Permission Policy in Custom Apps so not a Permissions Issue.

It is however not part of Set up policy under Teams Setup Policies (Not in Installed Apps or Pinned Apps but not blocked either .  Works fine this way in  Classic Teams)

When a user on (and only on) NEW teams client tries to interact with the custom app, they get a message :  You cannot send messages to this bot.

[image]

The Teams App however can send a proactive message to the end user.

Sometimes the user can send 1 or 2 messages before seeing the "you cannot send messages to this bot" and the input box is subsequently  greyed out.

In some cases, if the user searches and ADDs the Teams App using the ... menu on left rail, then the communication starts working.

**In other words, the new Teams client is somehow looking for apps INSTALLED by user or Admin rather than merely PERMITTED by a permission policy.**

This is even the app has been published in the Teams Admin Portal and permitted for all users in Global Policies.

Multiple forum postings on Microsoft Forums as well with no clear remediation.

It should not be necessary to both PERMIT and INSTALL an custom app.

Has anyone else found a fix/workaround?   Not possible to ask all our customers to pre install the App for all their users.  They have already permitted the app